# Post titles and thumbnails as links to custom post types?

Tags: posts, permalinks, customization, title

I am struggling with the php structure. How do I need to rewrite the code to get the links to the titles and thumbnails of the custom posts?

```
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <?php $pfportfolio = new WP_Query( 'post_type=portfolio', 'posts_per_page=-1' );?>
    <?php while ( $pfportfolio->have_posts() ) : $pfportfolio->the_post();?>

    <?php
        echo '<li class="span4" data-id="post-'.get_the_ID().'" data-type="'.$terms_as_text = strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', '', ' ', '' ) ).'">';
        **echo '<span class="projekte-title">';
        the_title();
        echo '</span>';
        echo '<div class="thumbnail">';
        the_post_thumbnail('home-feat');
        echo '</div>';**
        echo '</li>';?>

    <?php endwhile; ?>

   <?php  wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
```

I assume I need to integrate somehow

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>"></a>
```

but unfortunately I just dont understand how :(. Thanks so much for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should solve your problem...

```
<?php $pfportfolio = new WP_Query( array('post_type'=>'portfolio', 'posts_per_page'=>-1) ); ?>
<?php if ( $pfportfolio->have_posts() ): ?>
<ul class="thumbnails">
    <?php while ( $pfportfolio->have_posts() ) : $pfportfolio->the_post(); ?>
    <li class="span4" data-id="post-<?php echo esc_attr(get_the_ID()); ?>" data-type="<?php echo esc_attr(strip_tags( get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', '', ' ', '' ) ) ); ?>">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><span class="projekte-title"><?php the_title(); ?></span></a>
        <div class="thumbnail"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail('home-feat'); ?></a></div>
    </li>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$post->ID` to get current post id ( `get_permalink($post->ID)` ) and also can use function `the_permalink()` to show url

Comment: Well, inside the loop you can use `the_permalink` tag.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention "inside the loop"